# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transaction' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I keep getting this message in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transaction' of undefined.

I've tried deleting the DB, restarting live server,  moving the `add()` into the onsuccess, but I can't quite figure out what to do. This line seems ok to me: `const transaction = DB.transaction(['crm'], 'readwrite');` other answers I've checked were confusing

```
    (function(){
  let DB;
  const form = document.querySelector('#form');

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    conectDB();

    form.addEventListener('submit', validates);

  });

  
  function validates(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // read all the inputs
    const name = document.querySelector('#name').value;
    const email = document.querySelector('#email').value;
    const phone = document.querySelector('#phone').value;
    const company = document.querySelector('#company').value;

    if(name === '' || email === '' || phone === '' || company === '' ) {
      alertMessage('All Fields are required', 'error');

      return;
      }

      // create an object with the info
      const client = {
        name,
        email,
        phone,
        company,
        id: Date.now()
      }
      console.log(client)
      createNewClient(client);

    }

    function createNewClient(client) {
      const transaction = DB.transaction(['crm'], 'readwrite');
      const objectStore = transaction.objectStore('crm');
        // console.log(objectStore);

      objectStore.add(client);

      transaction.onerror = function() {
        alertMessage('Invalid Input ', 'error')
      }

      transaction.oncomplete = function() {
        alertMessage('Client Added ');

        setTimeout(() => {
          window.location.href = 'index.html';
        }, 3000);
      }

    }

  
})();
```

The connectDB function is this:

```
function conectDB() {
  const openConection = window.indexedDB.open('crm', 4);

  openConection.onerror = function() {
    console.log('Error')
  }

  openConection.onsuccess = function() {
    DB = openConection.result;
  }
}

function alertMessage(msg, type){

  const alert = document.querySelector('.alert');

  if(!alert) {
      // create the alert
      const divAlert = document.createElement('div');
      divAlert.classList.add('px-4', 'py-3', 'rounded', 'max-w-lg', 'mx-auto', 'mt-6', 'text-center', 'border', 'alert');

      if(type === 'error') {
        divAlert.classList.add('bg-red-100', 'border-red-400', 'text-red-700');
      } else {
        divAlert.classList.add('bg-green-100', 'border-green-400', 'text-green-700');
      }
      
      divAlert.textContent = msg;
      
      form.appendChild(divAlert);

      setTimeout(() => {
        divAlert.remove();
      }, 3000);
    }

  }
```

Comment: You mean `const transaction = DB.transaction(['crm'], 'readwrite');` this line is creating the problem. Okay, what I found out by looking at your code is variable `DB` is never get assigned anywhere so how can it has a property `transaction` in it. Before the line `const transaction = DB.transaction(['crm'], 'readwrite');`, just try `console.log(DB);` and tell me if it puts `undefined` on the screen or not.

Comment: If it puts `undefined` on the screen that means that you never assign variable `DB` a value and you are trying to access a property on a `undefined` value.

Comment: What does `connectDB()` function do? Can you also provide us details about that?

Comment: [Code github] (https://github.com/ccs211/crm-Only-JS)

Comment: I posted a solution to your problem.

Comment: I solved the problem, now try the solution I mentioned below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Solved CRM version]

I was able to create a new client by making some fixes. See I made some changes to your newClient.js file the main problem was even if we pass variable `DB` to the function `conectDB()` as an argument the only time it will get assigned a value is when the **connection to the database** is successful right? and this is the problem that the function `createNewClient()` is executed before the **connection to the database** is successful so what we need to do is we need to call the function `createNewClient()` after the **connection to the database** is successful
so we need to call the function `createNewClient()` once the **connection to the database** is successful and one way of doing this is calling the function `createNewClient()` inside of the `onsuccess` method as I have done in the following code. I had to make some local changes to `newClient.js` file but at least your problem is solved now and you can refactor the code later as you want.

Keep this thing in mind call `createNewClient()` function once the **connection to the database** is successful.

```
var DB;
const form = document.querySelector('#form');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  form.addEventListener('submit', validates);
});


function validates(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // read all the inputs
  const name = document.querySelector('#name').value;
  const email = document.querySelector('#email').value;
  const phone = document.querySelector('#phone').value;
  const company = document.querySelector('#company').value;

  if (name === '' || email === '' || phone === '' || company === '') {
    alertMessage('All Fields are required', 'error');

    return;
  }

  // create an object with the info
  const client = {
    name,
    email,
    phone,
    company,
    id: Date.now()
  }
  console.log(client)
  // createNewClient(client);
  conectDB(client);
}

function conectDB(client) {
  let openConection = window.indexedDB.open('crm', 4);

  openConection.onerror = function () {
    console.log('Error')
  }

  openConection.onsuccess = (event) => {
    DB = event.target.result;
    createNewClient(client);
  };
}

function createNewClient(client) {
  const transaction = DB.transaction(['crm'], 'readwrite');
  const objectStore = transaction.objectStore('crm', { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true });
  // console.log(objectStore);

  objectStore.add(client);

  transaction.oncomplete = function () {
    alertMessage('Client Added ');

    transaction.onerror = function () {
      alertMessage('Invalid Input ', 'error')
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
      window.location.href = 'index.html';
    }, 3000);
  };
}
```

Comment: Thxs for helping. It did't work. I still get Cannot read property 'transaction' of undefined. I'll keep working on it, wont quit

Comment: The problem was function `createNewClient()` was getting called before the connection to the database is successful so the variable `DB` never gets assigned.